# Adding to Individual Array Elements - C++

Tags: c++

I need to add either +0.25 or -0.25 to all elements within an array. Here is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int main() {

double i;


// Arrays
double x[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
double x2[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};



for(i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    const double pM[2] = {-1, 1};
    int randoid = rand() % 2;
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
        x2[i] = x[i] + pM[randoid]*0.25; //Error Line
    }
}

cout << x;
cout << x2;
}
```

I get this error at the marked line: "invalid types 'double[10][double] for array subscript"

Comment: Everything looks ok except for your output. Try `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cout << x2[i];` instead of `cout << x2;`

Comment: Also, your `i` is of type `double.` Change it to `int i`. Arrays have **integer** indices.

Comment: The type of i must be an integer. You've declared it as a double.

Comment: Thanks both of you. The problem is fixed, but the output is still broken. I get this as the output: "2.253.253.754.756.256.757.758.759.75-0.250x24fdc02". All the numbers not spaced with some weird hex at the end. Any help?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (even with the fix). Did you have some `#include` and some `using` lines that you forgot to paste?

Comment: `#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
`
 Think I have it as fixed as it's going to be. I think my IDE is being weird about printing the values side-by-side, but besides that it works.

Comment: Note that arrays are 0-indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 issues -

1. Change the type of `i` to `int`.
2. `x` and `x2` are arrays of size 10. You need to loop from `i =
   0` to `i = 9`. But you are looping from `i = 1` to `i = 10`. `x[10]`
   is out of bounds since `arrays` are 0 indexed.
3. `cout << x` - This is a wrong way to print an array. You need
   to loop through the array and print - e.g. -

   ```
   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       cout << x[i] << " ";
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `i` is a double. Then you write `x2[i]`.

It's not a very good error message; however with the `[]` operator, one of the operands must be a pointer and the other must be an *integer*.  There is no implicit conversion of floating-point to integer when using this operator.

To fix this change `double i;` to `int i;`

---

Another issue is that your code accesses out of bounds of the arrays. `double x2[10]` means that there are `10` elements whose indices are `0` through `9`.  But your loop tries to write to `x2[10]`. This causes undefined behaviour, which could explain your strange output.

---

There is also a potential logic error. Maybe you meant to use a different variable for the inner loop than the outer loop. As it stands, the inner loop will take `i` to `11` (or `10` if you fix the code) and then the outer loop will be complete and not execute any more iterations.

Based on your description though, perhaps you only meant to have one loop in the first place. If so, remove the outer loop and just leave the contents there.

Also you do not need two separate arrays, you could just perform the addition in-place.

---

Regarding the output, `cout << x` and `cout << x2` will output the number of the memory address at which the array is located.  To output the contents of the array instead you will need to write another loop, or use a standard library algorithm that iterates over containers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works, I converted to C

```
int main(  )
{

  int i = 0;
// Arrays
  double x[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
  double x2[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

  for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
  {
    const double pM[2] = { -1, 1 };
    int randoid = rand(  ) % 2;
    for ( i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
    {
      x2[i] = x[i] + pM[randoid] * 0.25;    //Error Line

      printf( "\nx[%d]==%2.2f", i, x[i] );
      printf( "\nx2[%d]==%2.2f", i, x2[i] );

    }
  }

}
```